# computer crashed while updating to utopic unicorn. everything gone quite wrong

Tags: data-corruption

I went to update to the latest version of ubuntu when it prompted me to, it took the best part of 24 hours to prepare the files which seemed weird but I have the internet connevtion from hell so I put it down to that. But then my computer crashed and when I restarted it I was lost in a loop of typing in my password, system program problem detected, password, system program problem detected - over and overforever. Ive tried booting the previous version of ubuntu from usb but cant get it to boot. Im pretty new to this stuff and am pretty lost :-(

Comment: Please help, is there anything I can do?